# Keras model taking too long to train

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, keras, lstm

So I have the following model for sentiment analysis (using pre trained word embeddings): 
[image]

And as visible, I have a pre trained embedding matrix and only about 500k trainable parameters. So why does it take a whole eternity to train this model? The batch size is 128 and number of epochs is 25. And the ETA for first epoch is about 10 minutes. I haven't even completed that.

Just to mention, I am not using CUDA or anything. I don't think I have a GPU enabled Tensorflow. And I'm willing to do anything to increase the speed. And I have Tensorflow 2.1.0.

Comment: There is not much that can be said, you did not include any of the important details. How much time is "a whole eternity"? Which CPU are you using to train this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here's the answer `I am not using CUDA or anything`. Training on CPU is much slower than on GPU. If you don't have high-performance enough video card, you can use several services such as Google Colab or Kaggle

Comment: I have RTX 2070. Will it help?

Comment: Well, this is definitely a high-performance card. To enable GPU support in tensorflow use this https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu